# Is it permissible to kill an animal and its mother without shechita?

Tags: halacha, animals, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, chulin-tractate, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

Halacha prohibits slaughtering an animal and its mother on the same day. My question is, does this prohibition apply if you kill those animals without the purpose of eating them and without shechita? For example, killing a sheep and its mother for wool.

Sources regarding the Halacha are appreciated.

Comment: *killing a sheep and its mother for wool* - That's not how you get wool. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep_shearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rambam ([MT Shechitah 12:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971838/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-12.htm)) answers your question and states it is permitted

> **The prohibition against slaughtering [an animal] and its offspring
> applies only with regard to ritual slaughter**, as the verse states: "Do
> not slaughter." [Implied] is that the prohibition involves the
> slaughter of both animals.
>
> **If, however, one chopped off the head of
> one of them or it became a nevelah in his hand, it is permitted to
> slaughter [the other]**. Similarly, if he slaughtered the first and
> chopped off the head of the second or it became a nevelah in his hand,
> he is not liable.